# Why would this query work in the Database Inspector section of the App Inspection in Android Studio, but not within a Room Query?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I have a table within my local SQLite database, the Class for it is as follows:

```
@Entity(tableName = "table_bp_reading")
class BPReading(
    var systolicValue: Int = 120,
    var diastolicValue: Int = 80,
    var pulseValue: Int = 72,
    var timeStamp: String = getDateTimeStamp(),
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var pId: Int = 0
) {
...
```

The relevant part of the Dao looks as such:

```
...
    @Query("SELECT * FROM table_bp_reading WHERE timeStamp BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate")
    fun getReadingsByDateRange(startDate: String, endDate: String): Flow<List<BPReading>>
...
```

The database inspector displays a table with
[the following entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCfNs.png).

Running the following query within the Database Inspector:

```
SELECT * FROM table_bp_reading WHERE timeStamp BETWEEN '2021-09-18 00:00:00' AND '2021-09-18 23:59:59'
```

[Gives the following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF2Jo.png).

However, when I try to observe the data using the following:

```
        bpReadingViewModel.bpReadingsByDate("2021-09-18 00:00:00", "2021-09-18 23:59:59").observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
                bpReading ->
            bpReading.let {
                bpReadingsByDate = it
                if(it.isNotEmpty()) bindDBDataToScatterChart()
            }
        })
```

No data is displayed on my end, the query results in an empty list.

Note, however, that if instead of using the full timestamp with time, I just use a date string such as "2021-09-18":

```
        bpReadingViewModel.bpReadingsByDate("2021-09-18", "2021-09-18").observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
                bpReading ->
            bpReading.let {
                bpReadingsByDate = it
                if(it.isNotEmpty()) bindDBDataToScatterChart()
            }
        })
```

And I also change the query from the Dao given previously to the following:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table_bp_reading WHERE DATE(timeStamp) BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate")
fun getReadingsByDateRange(startDate: String, endDate: String): Flow<List<BPReading>>
```

It works and it returns the 3 entries for that day as it is meant to. However, once I change the date range in the above, to filter between 2021-09-18 and 2021-09-19, it stops working again.

Please help, I am so confused by what is going on here.

EDIT:
Here's the relevant call from Repository:

```
    fun readingsByDateRange(s: String, e: String): Flow<List<BPReading>> =
        bpReadingDao.getReadingsByDateRange(e, s)
```

And the relevant call from the ViewModel for the class:

```
    fun bpReadingsByDate(s: String, e: String): LiveData<List<BPReading>> =
        repository.readingsByDateRange(s, e).asLiveData()
```

Which is why it is indeed bpReadingsByDate, and not getReadingsByDateRane. Sorry, this is my mistake for not being consistent with naming the function across files.

Comment: Can you post the table creation statement?

Comment: should  `bpReadingViewModel.bpReadingsByDate(....` not be `bpReadingViewMode.getReadingsByDateRange(....` ? (tested your query using room but without Flow and it works fine, so if you should be using `bpReadingsByDate` then the issue is probably with how `getREadingsByDateRange` is then invoked)

Comment: @MikeT I have added a bit of detail to the question. Do you think Flow could be the problem then?

Comment: @avalerio I am using Room, how would I pull up the creation statement since it does it for me?

Comment: should e and s be swapped? i.e. should you have **`bpReadingDao.getReadingsByDateRange(s, e)`** not `bpReadingDao.getReadingsByDateRange(e, s)`

Comment: Re getting create table SQL you can get this from the generated java in the class that is the @Database class suffixed by _Impl e.g. it would be `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_bp_reading` (`systolicValue` INTEGER NOT NULL, `diastolicValue` INTEGER NOT NULL, `pulseValue` INTEGER NOT NULL, `timeStamp` TEXT NOT NULL, `pId` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL)`

Comment: @MikeT you were indeed correct. Every test case that was not working, works well now. Swapping s & e in the Repository file to bpReadingDao.getReadingsByDateRange(s, e) did the trick. I thank you very much for pointing out my mistake, I can now get a good night's sleep!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is fine (tested), from your comments and edited question, you have swapped the start and end timestamps which will normally result in nothing being selected.

So you should change `bpReadingDao.getReadingsByDateRange(e, s)`to be `bpReadingDao.getReadingsByDateRange(s, e)`.